# Wordpress: Use post Excerpt to insert a URL

Tags: wordpress

I want to use the excerpt of a post in order to use that content on a

```
<a href="<?php the_excerpt(); ?>">Link</a>
```

But it only generates blank spaces and the url is not well inserted, any idea how to fix this?

here is a screen: [image: value]

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you in the loop ? Are you sure your post excerpt is filled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try using the function `get_the_excerpt()` instead. See documentation here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt

Write the result of get_the_excerpt() into a var and insert it whereever you want. Functions with "the_xxx" are meant to be used in the loop: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

edit:
I tried to reproduce your results and found the problem! There are some theme functions (within functions.php) which auto add a "read more" link to each generated excerpt no matter if you use the_excerpt or get_the_excerpt.

In my case the Twenty Eleven theme uses this:

```
/**
 * Set the post excerpt length to 40 words.
 *
 * To override this length in a child theme, remove
 * the filter and add your own function tied to
 * the excerpt_length filter hook.
 *
 * @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
 *
 * @param int $length The number of excerpt characters.
 * @return int The filtered number of characters.
 */
function twentyeleven_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 40;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'twentyeleven_excerpt_length' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'twentyeleven_continue_reading_link' ) ) :
/**
 * Return a "Continue Reading" link for excerpts
 *
 * @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
 *
 * @return string The "Continue Reading" HTML link.
 */
function twentyeleven_continue_reading_link() {
    return ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyeleven' ) . '</a>';
}
endif; // twentyeleven_continue_reading_link

/**
 * Replace "[...]" in the Read More link with an ellipsis.
 *
 * The "[...]" is appended to automatically generated excerpts.
 *
 * To override this in a child theme, remove the filter and add your own
 * function tied to the excerpt_more filter hook.
 *
 * @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
 *
 * @param string $more The Read More text.
 * @return The filtered Read More text.
 */
function twentyeleven_auto_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        return ' &hellip;' . twentyeleven_continue_reading_link();
    }
    return $more;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'twentyeleven_auto_excerpt_more' );

/**
 * Add a pretty "Continue Reading" link to custom post excerpts.
 *
 * To override this link in a child theme, remove the filter and add your own
 * function tied to the get_the_excerpt filter hook.
 *
 * @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
 *
 * @param string $output The "Continue Reading" link.
 * @return string The filtered "Continue Reading" link.
 */
function twentyeleven_custom_excerpt_more( $output ) {
    if ( has_excerpt() && ! is_attachment() && ! is_admin() ) {
        $output .= twentyeleven_continue_reading_link();
    }
    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'twentyeleven_custom_excerpt_more' );
```

I removed all the above code from functions.php (just to ensure there is no automated excerpt modification) and tried it again with the result you are looking for! Calling `get_the_excerpt()` shows a plain text without any formating or wired hrefs within.

To ensure the rest of your Page would still work I'd recommend to create your own excerpt function instead of removing this functions.

Comment: `get_the_excerpt` is not showing nothing, but `the_excerpt` it shows the value, but it shows with some `<p></p>` around

Comment: `<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>` should display the excerpt oif the ACTUAL post without any tags or styles. If it's empty you might need to specify the post first

Comment: this is the code that it shows:

`

value `

there is like a blank space, however, in the extract at the post there is none, here is a screen: http://i.imgur.com/5duRaLJ.jpg

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you, what's your goal? Would you like to have the content of the excerpt as value for the href tag? If so you'll have to put it there with echo. 

To remove the <p> tags you can also disable the auto p filter using `remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');` but ensure to reactivate it afterwards!

Comment: Exactly, but is rendering on a weird way, this is my code:

` <?php remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop'); ?>`
`<a href="<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>" target="_blank"/>`
`</a> `

but i only get this: http://i.imgur.com/kvk2kWM.jpg

notice that the first urls is the exceprt value, but them, it inserts the actual post url and that generates a conflict

Comment: OK! Now I got it right. I just tried to reproduce your problem and YES there's a Problem with some themes! There are some functions (depending on your theme) in the functions.php
`function twentyeleven_continue_reading_link()`, `function twentyeleven_auto_excerpt_more( $more )` and `function twentyeleven_custom_excerpt_more( $output )`

These functions automaticaly generate a "read more" link for each excerpt that you generate using get_the_excerpt or the_excerpt. Get rid of them or modify them in order to get a blank text without any links and auto text inside! Hope that helps you!

Comment: @Nighstalker YES! YES! that was the problem, my theme was adding some code on excerpt, THANKS!